# Elasticsearch: why exact match has lower score than partial match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-6

### my question

I search the word `form`, but the exact match word `form` is not the fisrt in result. Is there any way to solve this problem?

### my search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "word": "form"
    }
  }
}
```

### result

```
word             score
--------------------------
formulation      10.864353
formaldehyde     10.864353
formless         10.864353
formal   10.84412
formerly         10.84412
forma    10.84412
formation        10.574185
formula          10.574185
formulate        10.574185
format   10.574185
formally         10.574185
form     10.254687
former   10.254687
formidable       10.254687
formality        10.254687
formative        10.254687
ill-formed       10.054999
in form          10.035862
pro forma        9.492243
```

### POST my_index/_analyze

The word `form` in search has only one token `form`.

In index, `form` tokens are ["f", "fo", "for", "form"]; `formulation` tokens are ["f", "fo", ..., "formulatio", "formulation"].

### my config

#### filter

```
        "edgengram_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
```

#### analyzer

```
      "analyzer": {
        "abc_vocab_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "keyword_repeat",
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "edgengram_filter",
            "unique"
          ]
        },
        "abc_vocab_search_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "keyword_repeat",
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
```

#### mapping

```
        "word": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "abc_vocab_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "abc_vocab_search_analyzer"
        }
```

Comment: I've provided an answer below but I'm quite curious why your `min-gram` and `max-gram` has such a huge difference. It would be helpful if you can provide more info about your use case as I feel having `min-gram` set as 1 or 2 is not required and that is would simply consume huge space without providing any advantage. Same goes for max-ngram set as 20. Perhaps it is dependent on your domain but do thorough analysis on your index size if you decide to go for min and max ngram that high.

Comment: You can use the explain function ( .Explain() if is nest ) in your search to know why the scores are this ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the result in the way you see because you've implemented `edge-ngram` filter and that `form` is a sub-string of the words similar to it. Basically in inverted index it would also store the document ids that contains `formulation`, `formal` etc.

Therefore, your relevancy also gets computed in that way. You can refer to [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-similarity-in-elasticsearch) link and I'd specifically suggest you to go through sections `Default Similarity` and `BM25`. Although the present default similarity is `BM25`, that link would help you understand how scoring works.

You would need to create another sibling field which you can apply in a should clause. You can go ahead and create `keyword` sub-field with `Term Query` but you need to be careful about case-sensitivity.

Instead, as mentioned by @Val, you can create a sibling of `text` field with standard analyzer.

### Mapping:

```
   {
    "word":{
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "abc_vocab_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer": "abc_vocab_search_analyzer"
      "fields":{
        "standard":{
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

### Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "word": "form"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [                          <---- Note this
        {
          "match": {
            "word.standard": "form"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Looks overkill, if the analyzer is configured properly, ES by default gives the highest score to exact match, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja that's strange I've tested on ES 5.x version and get the same issue. I'm hoping you've tested on ES 7.x version.

Comment: yes, i tested it on latest 7.6, can you just use my example and see if it gives wrong result in 5.x ?

Comment: The sub-field approach is the correct one. However, the keyword field / term query combo will make the query case-sensitive, which is not ideal. To palliate that, I suggest to have a text field with a standard analyzer instead so you can have a match query in the should constraint.

Comment: @Amit, That's the first thing I did that and it gave me the wrong result!!

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal, u mean on 7.x also it's not giving highest score to exact match ? if you want I can share my postman collection, so that its easy to test you

Comment: I've tested on 5.x!! No 7.x here in my office laptop but I guess you must be right. I'm trying to find some details on release notes in any ES versions prior to 5.x to see when this change has happened.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Could you check number of shards your index has. I've tested it on shard of size `5`. When I changed it to `1`, it is working as per your use case but on shard of size 5, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal, by default in ES 7.X primary shards, is reduced to 1 and I am using default config.

Comment: I've tried on ES 7.6 but your code set doesn't work. Doesn't give me exact match ones at the top. I'm not sure how we can figure that ES pushes the exact match ones at the top in case of egde_ngrams

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal, its weird, did you again tried with 1 primary shard? for me it's pushing the exact match at top, let me know if you need, I can set up this on AWS instance and open the port 9200 publicly so that we can collaborate and test it together

Comment: Yes I've tried with 1 shard too on 7.6 and it doesn't give what you say!! :( Go ahead and share me the link, will try from postman!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208998/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-opster-es-ninja-kamal).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some issue in your custom analyzer, I created my custom `autocomplete` analyzer, which uses `edge_ngram` and `lowercase` filter and it works fine for me for your query and **returns me exact match on top and this is how Elasticsearch works, exact matches always have more score.**, So no need to explicitly create another field and boost that, As Elasticsearch by default boosts the exact match on tokens match.

### Index def

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Index few doc

```
{
   "title" : "formless"
}

{
   "title" : "form"
}

{
   "title" : "formulation"
}
```

### Search query on `title` field as provided in the question

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "form"
    }
  }
}
```

### Search result with exact match having highest score

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so-60523240-score",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.16410133,
            "_source": {
               "title": "form"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60523240-score",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.16410133,
            "_source": {
               "title": "formulation"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60523240-score",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.16410133,
            "_source": {
               "title": "formaldehyde"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60523240-score",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.16410133,
            "_source": {
               "title": "formless"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your type for this field is text which means ES will do full-text search analysis on this field. And ES search process is kind of finding results most similar to the word you have given.
 To accurately search word "form", change your search method to `match_phrase`
 Furthermore, you could also read articles below to learn more about different ES search methods:
https://www.cnblogs.com/yjf512/p/4897294.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html

Comment: `match_phrase` has same result. I just search only one word and use my own analyzer and search_analyzer, is there any advice?

Comment: One choice is to retype this field to term in which case full-text searhc will be disabled on this field. After that you could use termQuery to get the exact word you want. However this way may affect your own business concern if this field has a high chance to be searched in a full-text context.